# How can i view the content of a file created by a script on heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, puppeteer

I have a node.js script using [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) that

1. Visits a website
2. Scrape some element `innerText` and classes
3. Create a **.txt** file and save those scraped elements within the file
4. Repeat

This works locally but not after I deployed the app to [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/).

I have tried `heroku bash -a myappname`, and the `ls` to view the content, it only display the files and folder that I pushed to Heroku.

I also tried to clone the repo using `heroku git:clone -a myapp`, it only cloned and save my code files that I pushed to Heroku, and the **.txt** I am writing to disk is not there.

The screenshot below shows the expected text file is not there only the content I uploaded are there.

[image]

Here is the code pushed to Heroku:

```js
var http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function scrapeData(url) {
    var gotData = false;
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ args: ['--no-sandbox'] });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);

    //wait for all 6 balls and its innertext to appear
    await page.waitForFunction(
        () => {
            return (
                document.querySelectorAll('.ball')[2].innerText !== '' &&
                document.querySelectorAll('.ball')[3].innerText !== '' &&
                document.querySelectorAll('.ball')[4].innerText !== '' &&
                document.querySelectorAll('.ball')[5].innerText !== '' &&
                document.querySelectorAll('.ball')[6].innerText !== '' &&
                document.querySelectorAll('.ball')[7].innerText !== ''
            );
        },
        { timeout: 100000 }
    );

    //get the color and no of the six balls starting from the left
    const [ball1, ball2, ball3, ball4, ball5, ball6] = await page.evaluate(() => {
        const ball1 = document.querySelectorAll('.ball')[2];
        const ball2 = document.querySelectorAll('.ball')[3];
        const ball3 = document.querySelectorAll('.ball')[4];
        const ball4 = document.querySelectorAll('.ball')[5];
        const ball5 = document.querySelectorAll('.ball')[6];
        const ball6 = document.querySelectorAll('.ball')[7];
        //return the color and their numbers
        return [
            { number: ball1.innerText, color: ball1.classList[1].split('-')[1] },
            { number: ball2.innerText, color: ball2.classList[1].split('-')[1] },
            { number: ball3.innerText, color: ball3.classList[1].split('-')[1] },
            { number: ball4.innerText, color: ball4.classList[1].split('-')[1] },
            { number: ball5.innerText, color: ball5.classList[1].split('-')[1] },
            { number: ball6.innerText, color: ball6.classList[1].split('-')[1] },
        ];
    });

    //convert time to nigeria timezone
    function convertTZ(date, tzString) {
        return new Date(
            (typeof date === 'string' ? new Date(date) : date).toLocaleString('en-US', {
                timeZone: tzString,
            })
        );
    }
    const convertDate = convertTZ(new Date(), 'Africa/Lagos');

    //save the returned data in to a variable
    const result =
        convertDate.getHours() +
        ':' +
        convertDate.getMinutes() +
        ':' +
        convertDate.getSeconds() +
        ' ' +
        [
            `${ball1.color}-${ball1.number}`,
            `${ball2.color}-${ball2.number}`,
            `${ball3.color}-${ball3.number}`,
            `${ball4.color}-${ball4.number}`,
            `${ball5.color}-${ball5.number}`,
            `${ball6.color}-${ball6.number}`,
        ];

    //close the browser
    await browser.close();

    //create a file, and name it using today date & month in nigeria timezone
    var fileName =
        'day-' + convertDate.getDate() + '__' + 'month-' + convertDate.getMonth() + '.txt';

    //write the result to a file
    fs.appendFile(fileName, result + '\n', (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            gotData = true;
            if (gotData == true) {
                //reset gotData back to false
                gotData = false;

                //re-run scrapeData again
                callScrapeDataAgain();
            }
        }
    });
}

scrapeData(
    'https://logigames.bet9ja.com/Games/Launcher?gameId=11000&provider=0&sid=&pff=1&skin=201'
);

function callScrapeDataAgain() {
    scrapeData(
        'https://logigames.bet9ja.com/Games/Launcher?gameId=11000&provider=0&sid=&pff=1&skin=201'
    );
}
///*config.httpPort*/
//"Node server listening on port %d in %s mode", this.address().port, app.settings.env;
http.createServer((request, response) => {
    if (request.url == '/' && request.method == 'GET') {
        response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
        response.end('your app is working', 'utf-8');
    }
}).listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
    console.log('server working');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

See [Why are my file uploads missing/deleted?](https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted) in the Heroku help.

Heroku doesn't give you a real disk and any file writes are not guaranteed to persist.

They recommend you use external storage, such as Amazon S3, instead. They provide [a guide to using S3 with Node.js on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-node).